# generate csv with JasperReports

Tags: jasper-reports

I **have to** generate a simple csv file with JasperReports.

Which is the simplest jrxml file to do this?

I tried this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport 
xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports  http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" 
name="report5a" 
language="groovy">

<field name="col1" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="col2" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<field name="col3" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<field name="col4" class="java.lang.String"/>
<detail>
    <band height="16">
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="1000" height="15"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{col1}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="1000" y="0" width="1000" height="15"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{col2}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="2000" y="0" width="1000" height="15"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{col3}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="3000" y="0" width="1000" height="15"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{col4}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
</jasperReport>
```

It is working, but why should I have to provide width, or height parameters???
And if the x and width attributes are too low, then the values will be cut. For example, if all the of values (mentioned before) are divided by 1000, then the result will contains only 4 characters.

Ideas?

Thanks

Zsom

Comment: [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file it is a just text file. About what width and height parameters are you talking?

Comment: i have to genarete a csv from a database query. And i talking this width, and height parameter:<reportElement x="2000" y="0" width="1000" height="15"/>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JasperReports can certainly generate CSV files. But if that's your only goal, then there are much better choices than JR. It's vastly bigger than what you need.

To avoid having to set silly widths like you're doing now, you should set the property [net.sf.jasperreports.print.keep.full.text](http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.print.keep.full.text).

EDIT: with that property set then your field widths can be any positive value. You don't need to worry about making them wide enough to accomodate the text without wrapping.

Comment: I know that there are better choices, but i have to use this.
This property prevents text cutting, so it's useful for me.
But I still hvae to take care about the widths and x attributes.

Comment: No, you should not need to worry about the widths. Yes, you need to worry about the x attributes. Yes, if you're told to whack a nail into a board using a screwdriver... it's possible to do it. Good luck.

Comment: Good point! I'll update the response to mention that 0-width fields won't work.